# String of numbers to array of numbers

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and am messing around with conversions of types because I need it for my first program.

Basically I'm trying to convert a singular string of numbers into an array of numbers.

eg. `"609" -> [6,0,9]`

```
const RADIX: u32 = 10;
let lines: Vec<String> = read_lines(filename);

let nums = lines[0].chars().map(|c| c.to_digit(RADIX).expect("conversion error"));

println!("Line: {:?}, Converted: {:?}", lines[0], nums);
```

I tried the above and the output is as follows:

```
Line: "603", Converted: Map { iter: Chars(['6', '0', '3']) }
```

Which I assume isn't correct. I'd need it to be just a pure array of integers so I can perform operations with it later.

Comment: Rust iterators are lazy. This means that iterating over your string characters and applying adapters does not do actually anything except creating a variable of type `Map`. Only when you call `collect`, this is when the iteration actually occurs.

Comment: Also note that this is not going to work as you expect if you every change the `RADIX`, because the string "609" is already in base 10. If you wanted to gets the digits in an other base, you'd have to convert that string to a number first, and then get the digits.

Comment: Good to know, but I don't need to do that in this context, so it's all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, add the type ascription to `nums`:

```
let nums: Vec<u32> = ...
```

and end the method chain with `.collect()` to turn it into a vector of digits.